# How to download "portal-impl.jar" jar file's source code?

Tags: liferay

How to download "portal-impl.jar" jar file's source code?

Answer (score 2):

Liferay sources are hosted on GitHub - https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal.

You can [download](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/archive/master.zip) them from there.